# Algorithms of Joining arrays in numpy

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm new in numpy, I understand the methods of "Joining arrays" in lower shape such as (n1, n2) beacause we can visualize, like a matrix.

But I don't undestand the logic in higher dimensions (n0, ...., n_{d-1}) of course I can't visualize that. To visualize I usually imagine a multidimensional array like a tree, so (n0, ...., n_{d-1}) means that at level (axis) i of tree **every node** has n_{i} children. So at level 0 (the root) we have n0 children and so on.

In substance what is the formal exact definiton of "Joining arrays" algorithms?

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html

Comment: What's your reference for 'joining arrays'?  That's not how `numpy` documentation talks.

Comment: Tank you, I refer to this: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html

Comment: OK, that clairifies your question.  The basic operation is `concatenate` which makes a new array from a list of arrays.  It doesn't change the number of dimensions.  The other functions tweak the dimensions in various ways before calling `concatenate`

Comment: It may help if you first understand https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html, the basics of a multi dimensional array.  The join functions don't create anything new or different.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see I can illustrate some basic array operations.

First make a 2d array.  Start with a 1d, [0,1,...5], and reshape it to (2,3):

```
In [1]: x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [2]: x
Out[2]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

I can join 2 copies of `x` along the 1st dimension (`vstack`, v for vertical also does this):

```
In [3]: np.concatenate([x,x], axis=0)
Out[3]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Note that the result is (4,3); no new dimension.

Or join them 'horizontally':

```
In [4]: np.concatenate([x,x], axis=1)
Out[4]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],        # (2,6) shape
       [3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5]])
```

But if I supply them to `np.array` I make a 3d array (2,2,3) shape:

```
In [5]: np.array([x,x])
Out[5]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]]])
```

This action of `np.array` is really no different from making a 2d array from nested lists, `np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`.  We could just add a layer of nesting, just like Out[5} without the line breaks. I tend to think of this 3d array as having 2 blocks, each with 2 rows and 3 columns.  But the names are just a convenience.

`stack` acts like `np.array`, making a 3d array.  It actually changes the input arrays to (1,2,3) shape, and `concatenates` on the first axis.

```
In [6]: np.stack([x,x])
Out[6]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]]])
```

`stack` lets us join the array in other ways

```
In [7]: np.stack([x,x], axis=1)      # expand to (2,1,3) and concatante
Out[7]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[3, 4, 5],
        [3, 4, 5]]])
In [8]: np.stack([x,x], axis=2)       # expand to (2,3,1) and concatenate
Out[8]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2]],

       [[3, 3],
        [4, 4],
        [5, 5]]])
```

`concatenate` and the other `stack` functions don't add anything new to basic numpy arrays.  They just provide a way(s) of making a new array from existing ones.  There aren't any special `algorithms`.

If it helps you could think of these join functions as creating a new "blank" array, and filling it with copies of the source arrays.  For example that last `stack` can be done with:

```
In [9]: res = np.zeros((2,3,2), int)
In [10]: res
Out[10]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]]])
In [11]: res[:,:,0] = x
In [12]: res[:,:,1] = x
In [13]: res
Out[13]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2]],

       [[3, 3],
        [4, 4],
        [5, 5]]])
```

Comment: In case of lower dimensione 1D, 2D, 3D is clear but in more higher dimension how can interpret or visualize concatenate?